# Azure Devops pull request update content after reject

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-merge, pull-request

We are working with Azure Devops, merge into main only via PR.
If the QA team reject the PR because of some bug in the code, and the developer fixed the bug - do we have to open a new PR?

- Can we not update the code on the current PR and re-submit it?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, any update of this? Does Vonc's answer answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rejecting a PR is a [vote on PR changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/review-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#vote-on-pr-changes)

It odes not prevent you to push additional commits on it, requesting for a feedback reset, and a new vote.

You can use a [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/about-pull-requests?view=azure-devops#branch-policies-and-pull-requests):

> To reset votes whenever a PR author pushes new changes, select `Reset code reviewer votes when there are new changes` in the Require a minimum number of reviewers branch policy.